# runAsync of CompleteableFutures

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written the below code

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Runnable task = () -> { System.out.println( " This is task " +Thread.currentThread().getName() ); };
       CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(task,service);

        System.out.println( " Printing here -- "  + cf.get());
```

I get the following output

```
This is task pool-1-thread-1
 Printing here -- null
```

My question is why I am getting null?Is it because runAsync does not return anything hence cf.get() is always null.

Then another doubt I have I have created ThreadPool of 3 threads
.So shouldn't "This is task" be printed 3 times?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting null because cf.get() returns null. Not because cf is null. If cf was null, you'd be thrown a null pointer exception.

Creating a threadpool of size 3 means that you created a threadpool where 3 tasks would be executed in parallel by the executor service. You created a single task, hence the single output.

Answer (score 2):

Your type `CompletableFuture<Void>` means "something will run, and then when it's done, I'll get a `Void` reference. The lambda on the line before implicitly returns a `null` reference for the Void which is expected to meat the contract.

Try for example this, to see how it could work with an `Integer` reference:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Callable<Integer> task = () -> {
    System.out.println( " This is task " +Thread.currentThread().getName() );
    return 5+5;
};
Future<Integer> cf = service.submit(task);
System.out.println( " Printing here -- "  + cf.get());
```

As for why you don't get the answer three times, it's because your thread pool has three threads. You've only submitted one task to it, though.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `task` has no return value hence it's return type is `Void`. After running and completing your `task` you always get a `null` value regardless of how much time you wait!
2. When you use `cf.get()` you are blocking current thread to evaluate the `task`.
3. Regardless of how many threads are in your thread pool (`Executor`), your `task` will be run only in one of the threads.